# Python - improving logging to file and console using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to download a file on CAN bus using `python-can`. It involves sending data very quickly (in the order of 2-3 messages per millisecond). I am trying to log to file these messages without impacting the speed of sending. Doing the file I/O slows down the sending due to the logging overhead. I tried various methods to improve this (including using queues and reading the queue from another thread but this was not much better - possibly due to GIL). Most of these tests started with using the Python `logging` module and trying various handlers (`QueueHandler/QueueListener`, `MemoryHandler`, etc).

I've managed to make some significant improvements by moving the file I/O into a separate process. I initially ran into an issue with the overhead of sending data from one process to another - so I now buffer it. Now, instead of taking 150% longer with direct file I/O in the main process, I see ~20% increase in time.

I thought that, since this is running in another process, I could also `print()` the data to console (which I know is relative expensive) but I see a huge increase in the file download time.

What is happening that means the `print()` affects the main process even though it is running in a child process?

*Code below:*

`file_logger_mp()` is called from the main process and it starts the child process that does the logging. The main process then uses the `log_hdl` function to add a message to the buffer. When the buffer reaches a certain size (100) it is sent to the child process for logging to file or printing to console.

Device: rpi4. And the main process uses asyncio, in case that affects it.

```py
def file_logger_mp(logger_name: str, log_file_pth: str):

    conn_rec, conn_send = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    log_hdl_c = MyLogger(conn_send)
    log_hdl = log_hdl_c.log_hdl    # This is used by main code to provide log messages to child process
    
    listener = MyProcess(conn_rec, log_file_pth)
    atexit.register(log_hdl_c.final_flush, listener)
    listener.start()    # Start the child process

    return log_hdl, listener

class MyLogger():
    def __init__(self, conn_send) -> None:
        self.buffer = []
        self.conn_send = conn_send

    def log_hdl(self, msg):
        self.buffer.append(msg)
        if len(self.buffer) > 100:
            self.conn_send.send(self.buffer)
            self.buffer.clear()

    def final_flush(self, listener):
        self.conn_send.send(self.buffer)
        listener.terminate()

class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, queue, f_hdl):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()
        self.queue = queue
        self.f_hdl = f_hdl

    def run(self):
        f = open(self.f_hdl, "w+")
        while not self.exit.is_set():
            try:
                record = self.queue.recv()

                for msg in record:
                    output = str(msg)
                    f.write(output+'\n')
                    print(output) # This `print()` causes large delays to main process?!
                record.clear()
            except Exception:
                import sys, traceback
                print('Whoops! Problem:', file=sys.stderr)
                traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
        for msg in record:  # Flush any pending records before finishing
            f.write(str(msg)+'\n')
        f.close()

    def terminate(self):
        self.exit.set()
```

Comment: what is the type of `msg` in `log_hdl`? is it a `logging.LogRecord`? that contains a lot of extra processing / information to make `logging` very flexible, but not necessarily fast. if you can capture the data coming off the CAN bus in `bytes`, and never convert it, you will reduce memory and cpu pressure. It also simplifies (reduces overhead) transferring the data to another process if you then still need more cpu to process the data before dumping it to a file.

Comment: `msg` is my own class containing various bits of data. I did recognise the overhead due to processing. But the bit I am struggling to understand is why the two processes don't seem to be decoupled...why does printing in one process significantly affect the other one?!

Comment: I'd have to see more of the program to know.. How you're timing, how you're getting can messages.. just a few functions to work on here is not enough. I'd say what you have posted so far shouldn't be *terribly* slow (pickle and unpickle batches of messages, convert to str, then write to file), but again it's hard to say. Is the sending device waiting for ack messages so packets aren't missed? how is the incoming data being buffered? is the child waiting on the parent at any time? If both are using stdout, are they just stepping over eachother on a shared resource?